# Why does cycles render this scene as black, while evee renders it like I expect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cn17ibk3u8xpaw7/zwart.blend?dl=0

I probably changed some setting, but I've been looking everywhere and I can't find what I've done.

I deleted everything from my .blend file and added just a cube, so it's not in the materials or objects. Some cycles setting I guess.

I realize this is probably some stupid thing and I feel a bit anxious to ask other people to solve it for me, but I am so annoyed that I can't find out what it is...

So If it is not some obvious beginner mistake, please don't waste any time on this, I'll just append all collections into a new .blend file if all else fails...

Comment: *Properties Panel > View Layer > Filter*: These checkboxes are usually enabled and are restricting rendering.

Comment: @Leander Thanks!, That was it. I have no clue when I disabled those :-D .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Leander's comment:

The checkboxes in
Properties Panel > View Layer > Filter
were somehow disabled.